# Is that possible to run an app that uses a VPN and another one that doesn't use VPN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

Ok, so.
I'm running a home server (under windows) with an emby server app.
I need my freinds to be able to reach my server while I use a VPN to download new movies and series.
Currently, while VPN is active, the server becomes unreachable.
I had an idea to make this work. My idea was to use "ForceBindIP" tool to force emby server to use my physical network card without using VPN's virtual network card, but it does not work at all!
Has someone another idea? Or maybe is it just impossible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Windows Firewall to accomplish this.

> 1.Connect to your VPN as you normally would.
>
> 2.Open the Network and Sharing Center - right-click on the Internet
> connection icon in the taskbar and choose "Open Network and Sharing
> Center" (see below)
>
> 3.You should see (at least) two networks listed under "View Your Active
> Networks" - your VPN connection and one called "Network" - a.k.a. your
> ISP Connection. Ensure that your VPN is a "Public Network", and your
> ISP connection is "Home Network". If you need to change either
> connection, click it and an option window will appear (see below).
>
> 4.Go to the Control Panel and click System and Security (see below).
>
> 5.In the resulting window, click Windows Firewall (see below).
>
> 6.In the Windows Firewall window, click Advanced Settings on the left
> pane (see below). Note: You must be logged in as an Adminstrator to
> make changes to the Firewall Settings.
>
> 7.You should see a window titled Windows Firewall with Advanced
> Security. In this window, click Inbound Rules (see below).
>
> 8.On the right pane, you will see an option for a New Rule. Click it
> (see below).
>
> 9.In the New Inbound Rule Wizard (which should appear), do the
> following:
>
> - Choose Program and click Next.
> - Choose the program you wish to block all traffic to except on the VPN connection, and click next.
> - Choose Block the Connection.
> - Tick Domain and Private. Make sure Public is left unticked.
>
> 10.Repeat Step 9 for Outbound Rules.

For more details, please refer to the following link:

[How to Always / Only Use VPN Connection and block ISP - Make Bittorrent only use VPN Connection](http://practicalrambler.blogspot.com/2011/01/windows-7-firewall-how-to-always-use.html)